# Check the datatype of Pandas Series & convert String to Number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a Series(ts) like this, where i replaced the empty values with ones:

```
       Date
    2013-04-28             1
    2013-04-29             1
    2013-04-30             1
    2013-05-01             1
           ...    
    2018-03-11    6296370000
    2018-03-12    6457400000
    2018-03-13    5991140000

Name: Volume, Length: 1808, dtype: object
```

`ts.dtype` gives me : `dtype('O')`

how can i check if the value of the Series is a number, and in case it is a String,convert it to a number/int?

thx in advance

Comment: You could use `isdigit()`

Answer (score 0):

Using `apply`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": ["1","1","1","1", "a", "a"]})
print(df["a"].apply(lambda x: int(x) if x.isdigit() else x))
```

**Output:**

```
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    a
5    a
Name: a, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `to_numeric`

```
pd.to_numeric(df.a,errors='coerce').fillna(df.a)
Out[204]: 
   a
0  1
1  1
2  1
3  1
4  a
5  a
```

More info

```
pd.to_numeric(df.a,errors='coerce').fillna(df.a).apply(type)
Out[217]: 
0    <class 'float'>
1    <class 'float'>
2    <class 'float'>
3    <class 'float'>
4      <class 'str'>
5      <class 'str'>
Name: a, dtype: object
```